# time command running on function wont let the function print

Tags: unix, time, solaris, ksh

I have a problem with my code. It doesn't print out an error, it works but it doesn't do what I actually need it to do. I won't be posting all of the code because it is not needed, I will just post the line we need.

So I have this line of code:

```sh
TIME1=$( { time awkfun ; } 2>&1 >/dev/null);
```

Where `awkfun` is a function that should print 500 integers, and `TIME1` is a variable to store the time that the function will need to run and print. Problem is that normally as I said the function would print around 500 integers in this occasion though that I am using this, it just runs and does the calculations but is not printing. So it actually runs the `awkfun` function but doesn't let it print, in the time output for this function I also need the time it needs to print everything.

How to do that?

I hope I explained it as good as possible, if any questions arise please don't hesitate to comment, thanks in advance!

**P.S**

Running in ksh in oracle solaris.

Comment: Why do you redirect everything to /dev/null (`2>&1 >/dev/null`) ?

Comment: @Michael because if i dont do that, what i get in the TIME1 variable is the output of the awkfun function, and what i need to be set in the TIME1 variable is the output of the time command. Though now that i get like this the time in the TIME1 variable, it doesnt print on the terminal what function awkfun should print.

Comment: Redirect your output to a real file and see if it contains what you are looking for

Comment: Try something like: `TIME1=\`time (awkfun > /tmp/out) 2>&1\`` [or equiv]

Comment: @Michael it does contain the output of the awkfun, but i dont need it to be stored in a file, i need it as the script is running to print it as it runs the function, because i need to get the timing of it.

Comment: @CraigEstey i  dont want the output to be stored in a file, i need it to be printed on the terminal.

Comment: How about `TIME1=\`time (awkfun > /dev/tty) 2>&1\`` then?

Comment: @CraigEstey good job man, thats it, i just had to add time before awkfun in order to ge tthe time back, but it works fine.... post your solution to the answers so i can tick it.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct sequence. Adjust as needed:

```
TIME1=`time (awkfun > /dev/tty) 2>&1`
```

Comment: If the OP is really using `ksh`, there is no need to revert to the legacy backquote syntax instead of keeping the better `$( )` one.

Comment: @jlliagre The main point was to get the diversions correct. I didn't have `ksh` [or solaris], so I tested with a more universal syntax. This was originally done in a top comment with the phrase _"something like"_ and OP suggested posting the answer to be upvoted. As to `ksh` syntax, the _"adjust as needed"_ should have covered it

Comment: No problem. Just to clarify, I didn't wrote your reply is incorrect. On the opposite, it provides a working solution to the OP and addresses the actual issue. My only minor point was the new `$( ... )` syntax was introduced almost three decades ago precisely by `ksh` and since then standardized by POSIX and adopted by all Bourne style shells, except by the legacy original Bourne shell which is not any more `/bin/sh` in current Solaris release (11). The fact the OP already uses that syntax and that it doesn't trigger an error message implies there was no reason to revert to the older syntax.

Comment: @jlliagre Sigh. Circa 1981 I wrote a lot of `csh` (it was the same on all systems, but `sh` was not yet standardized). But, a friend complained, thinking I was nuts. Later, he said: "Now everybody's doing scripts--you were way ahead on this". Circa 1990, I discovered `perl`. I realized I could replace all of `*sh`, `sed`, `awk`, `cut`, pipes, etc. with a single self contained script that could be precompiled [and syntax checked via `-c`] (i.e. a superset). And, `perl`/`python` can also do full programs that might otherwise be in C but difficult/slow for `*sh`. So, I've never looked back